# Button click before scraping an html table

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape an HTML table from a webpage where you need to click a button first before the table shows up. I tried this code but I got an error saying that such button does not exist. (`NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element`) Can someone please help give me some guidance?

This is the code I used:

```
# set up the Firefox webdriver
options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# navigate to the website
driver.get('https://datawarehouse.dbd.go.th/company/profile/5/0245552001018')

# wait for the table to be loaded
driver.implicitly_wait(1)  # wait for up to 1 second

#click button 
button = driver.find_element("link text","Financial Information")
button.click()

# extract the HTML content of the table
html = driver.find_element("xpath", '//table').get_attribute('outerHTML')

# close the web browser
driver.quit()

# convert the HTML content to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_html(html)[0]

# print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: the link to the website probably needs a login, because it redirects to main page. Post relevant HTML of the button you want to click.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
# Open the below URL
driver.get('https://datawarehouse.dbd.go.th')
# wait applied
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
# below line clicks the OK button on the pop-up
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnWarning').click()
# below line switches the language from TH to English
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="slider round"]').click()
# Below line opens the required URL
driver.get('https://datawarehouse.dbd.go.th/company/profile/5/0245552001018')
# Below line clicks on Financial Information menu
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@id="menu2"]')
button.click()
# Capture the HTML of the table
html = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card-body']/table").get_attribute('outerHTML')
print(html)
driver.quit()
```

I ran the above code and it worked fine. Below is the console output:

```
<table class="table table-hover text-end table-fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle col-fixed">Unit : Baht</th>         
                        <th colspan="2">2018</th>
                        <th colspan="2">2019</th>
                        <th colspan="2">2020</th>
                        <th colspan="2">2021</th>
                        <th colspan="2">2022</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="text-center">                        
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>%Change</th>  

                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>%Change</th>

                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>%Change</th>
                        
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>%Change</th>
                        
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>%Change</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-start col-fixed">Accounts Receivable</th> 
                        <td>342,438,019.00</td>
                        <td>12.63</td>
```

The console output is huge, so I have pasted only the part of it.

Note: I have just printed the HTML, you can convert this to dataframe.

Comment: Thank you Shawn! I tried running it and I got an error. (Btw I'm using Google Collab - not sure if that's relevant)
This is the error:
'ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <span class="slider round"> is not clickable at point (1093,48) because another element <div class="modal-backdrop fade"> obscures it'

Comment: I also tried disabling the line that switches the language from TH to English. (That's the one that caused the error.) Then, I got this error:

'ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <span id="menu2" class="tab2"> is not clickable at point (269,160) because another element <div class="preload"> obscures it'

Comment: Does you code maximize the browser window before it starts to locate elements? 'driver.maximize_window()'

Comment: No it didn't. Should I add that line to maximize the browser window?

Comment: Yes, maximize the window immediately after `driver.get('https://datawarehouse.dbd.go.th')`. `ElementClickInterceptedException` implies that some other element is over shadowing the desired element. Try maximizing the window, and let me know if it works.